# Converting many bits to Base 10

Tags: c++, math, binary, numbers, largenumber

I am building a class in C++ which can be used to store arbitrarily large integers.  I am storing them as binary in a vector.  I need to be able to print this vector in base 10 so it is easier for a human to understand.  I know that I could convert it to an int and then output that int.  However, my numbers will be much larger than any primitive types.  How can I convert this directly to a string.

Here is my code so far.  I am new to C++ so if you have any other suggestions that would be great too.  I need help filling in the `string toBaseTenString()` function.

```
class BinaryInt
{
private:
    bool lastDataUser = true;
    vector<bool> * data;
    BinaryInt(vector<bool> * pointer)
    {
        data = pointer;
    }
public:
    BinaryInt(int n)
    {
        data = new vector<bool>();
        while(n > 0)
        {
            data->push_back(n % 2);
            n = n >> 1;
        }
    }
    BinaryInt(const BinaryInt & from)
    {
        from.lastDataUser = false;
        this->data = from.data;
    }
    ~BinaryInt()
    {
        if(lastDataUser)
            delete data;
    }
    string toBinaryString();
    string toBaseTenString();
    static BinaryInt add(BinaryInt a, BinaryInt b);
    static BinaryInt mult(BinaryInt a, BinaryInt b);
};
BinaryInt BinaryInt::add(BinaryInt a, BinaryInt b)
{
    int aSize = a.data->size();
    int bSize = b.data->size();
    int newDataSize = max(aSize, bSize);
    vector<bool> * newData = new vector<bool>(newDataSize);
    bool carry = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < newDataSize; i++)
    {
        int sum = (i < aSize ? a.data->at(i) : 0) + (i < bSize ? b.data->at(i) : 0) + carry;
        (*newData)[i] = sum % 2;
        carry = sum >> 1;
    }
    if(carry)
        newData->push_back(carry);
    return BinaryInt(newData);
}
string BinaryInt::toBinaryString()
{
    stringstream ss;
    for(int i = data->size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ss << (*data)[i];
    }
    return ss.str();
}
string BinaryInt::toBaseTenString()
{
    //Not sure how to do this
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use `std::vector<bool>` here, and you don't want a pointer to a vector.  Something like `std::vector<unsigned> data;`, plus an additional flag for the sign, would be the simplest.

Comment: And for the conversion, you'll need to implement `/` and `%` (preferably with `int` as well as with `BinaryInt`).

Comment: Why don't I want to use a pointer?  If I'm storing so much data shouldn't it go on the stack.  I also think using the point makes copying my class much more efficient since I don't have to copy over the data.

Comment: The size of `vector<bool>` isn't particularly large, regardless of how many elements it contains.  And for something like `BinaryInt`, you need value semantics.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said in your OP that "my numbers will be much larger than any primitive types", but just hear me out on this.

In the past, I've used std::bitset to work with binary representations of numbers and converting back and forth from various other representations.  std::bitset is basically a fancy std::vector with some added functionality.  You can read more about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) if it sounds interesting, but here's some small stupid example code to show you how it could work:

```
std::bitset<8> myByte;

myByte |= 1;  // mByte = 00000001
myByte <<= 4; // mByte = 00010000
myByte |= 1;  // mByte = 00010001

std::cout << myByte.to_string() << '\n';  // Outputs '00010001'
std::cout << myByte.to_ullong() << '\n';  // Outputs '17'
```

You can access the bitset by standard array notation as well.  By the way, that second conversion I showed (to_ullong) converts to an unsigned long long, which I believe has a max value of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.  If you need larger values than that, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate (backwards) your `vector<bool>` and accumulate the corresponding value when the iterator is true:

```
int base10(const std::vector<bool> &value)
{
    int result = 0;
    int bit = 1;

    for (vb::const_reverse_iterator b = value.rbegin(), e = value.rend(); b != e; ++b, bit <<= 1)
        result += (*b ? bit : 0);

    return result;  
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/zK6eOw).

Beware! this code is only a guide, you will need to take care of int overflowing if the value is pretty big.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That would work, however, I will be dealing with millions of bits.  I need to skip the converting to and int and go directly to a string.